# Open iframe in jquery and then read contents from it

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm new at jquery, but I need to open some contents in an Iframe (contents living in another domain), which of course loads an entire html page from other location, and then I need to traverse the body contents to find some text in a table in there...

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have also tried to use a popup window with window.open, but I can't find a way to traverse contents of this new window using jquery, that's why I thought about the iframe solution...

Thanks! and excuse the much newbie question...

Comment: If the iframe content is from another domain, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: yes, the content is from another domain :/ ... it's not possible even if I only want to read contents? I don't want to manipulate anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>use [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to find the element inside the iframe</s>

```
$("#iframeID").contents().find("#elemInIframe")
```

edit:

as @elclanrs said in the comments, you **cannot** *access the iframe* contents if the iframe **doesn't belong to your domain**

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do too, but I get nothing at all... as I mentioned in the comment of the previous answer, the contents of the Iframe is from another domain, other than the one I'm using... :S

Comment: then there is no way you can access the iframe contents, due to security restrictions you cannot access the contents of the iframe that belongs to another domain

Comment: I know this may sound wrong, but then why Firefox extensions such as Firebug allow this kind of manipualtion? Sure the answer involves no javascript at all, and that's why?

Comment: i dont know for real but the firebug runs as the extension of  the fire fox browser in a sandbox environment, that is why when you try to intall a new extension in chrome it warns you that the extensions have access to your browser history etc... so i dont see the analogy here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('iframe').bind('myCustomTrigger', function() {
 alert('hello');
 });
 });
 $("#frameDemo").contents().find("a").css("background-color","#BADA55");
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <iframe src="iframe_file.html" width="800px" height="600px">
 </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```